# jQuery 1.4.2: How to hide element which is fading in

Tags: jquery

I want to, under certain circumstances, hide an element which is currently fading in.  This works in later versions of jQuery, but not in jQuery 1.4.2, which is the version the website I am working on is using, and cannot be upgraded.  How can I get this working in 1.4.2?

**HTML**

```
<div class="fade">BLAH</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fade {
    display:none;   
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('.fade').show(1000);
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.fade').hide();
}, 500);
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WcUUd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop the animation and clear the queue:

```
$('.fade').show(1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.fade').stop(true, true).hide();
}, 500);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WcUUd/4/**

Comment: Now that I see this answer, I actually remember learning this before like 2 years ago.  Thanks!